# Problem with package bm

Tags: packages, bm

I have a problem with the package bm, and there may be a conflict with other packages. Or, maybe, I don't understand how this package works.

Here is a MWE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

                 
\begin{document}
  $\bm{\cos\theta}$
  
  $\bm{\theta}$
\end{document}
```

And here is the result:

[image]

As you can see, the theta is missing on the first line and not on the second line, and I don't understand why. If I comment the first three `\usepackage`, it works fine and I find that even more strange

Comment: Not at pc, but does it make a difference if you remove the frenchmath option?

Comment: @daleif no you can cut the preamble down to `\usepackage{newtxmath}\usepackage{bm}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A quick workaround you can add `\relax`

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{newtxtext}
\usepackage[frenchmath]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{bm}

                 
\begin{document}

  $\bm{\cos\theta}$

  $\bm{\cos\relax\theta}$
  
  $\bm{\theta}$
\end{document}
```

adding `\show\cos` before and after newtxmath shows

```
> \cos=macro:
->\protect \cos  .
```

and

```
> \cos=macro:
->\qopname \relax o{cos}.
l.5 \show\cos
```

and basically `bm` doesn't understand the second form.  You get the same definition and same failure just using `amsmath` not `newtxmath`)

simpler test case

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}


%\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{bm}
\bmdefine\bcos{\cos}
\show\bcos


\begin{document}


\end{document}
```

uncommenting `amsmath` does not end well here...

If you modify `bm.sty` adding a line defining `\qopname` at line 195 so it looks like

```
...
    \let\DN@\copy
    \let\FN@\copy
    \let\next@\copy
    \def\qopname##1##2##3{\mathop{\qopname{##1}{##2}{##3}}}%
```

Then it works (in this case at least, may not be quit ethe right fix in general) , if you do this please modify the top to say

```
\ProvidesPackage{bm}
          [2021/04/25 v1.2e Bold Symbol Support (DPC/FMi) +qopname fix]
```

Comment: Thank you David. I will use the \relax command. I am not good enough in LaTeX to modify the bm.sty. And I suppose that if I do so, I will lose my modifications when there is an update of the package (which, I guess, will overwrite the modifications)

Comment: @Didier not if you place the modified one in eg the same folder as the document, also the next update will probably fix this so it won't matter if it over-writes your local fix:)

Comment: Thank you for your help. I am gonna try to modify the sty file